# maximumContentSizeCategory in iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, ios14, dynamic-type-feature

In our recent project, we're trying to add **Dynamic Text Sizing** support. Our app is supporting *iOS 14* and above.

In *iOS 15*, we can limit the text sizing using the property `maximumContentSizeCategory` and `minimumContentSizeCategory`.

```
label.maximumContentmSizeCategory = .accessibilityLarge
```

**Question** - What is the alternative of `maximumContentSizeCategory` and `minimumContentSizeCategory` in *iOS 14*?

Comment: I suppose the `minimumScaleFactor` property of a label's text may be a good candidate ⟹https://stackoverflow.com/a/64088080/3825084

Comment: see the accepted answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58830375/how-to-specify-a-minimum-uicontentsizecategory-for-uifontmetrics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UIApplication.shared.preferredContentSizeCategory` to decide which `preferredContentSizeCategory` to use with `UITraitCollection`

**Example:**

```
func getPreferredFont(textStyle: UIFont.TextStyle, weight: UIFont.Weight? = nil) -> UIFont {
    let preferredContentSizeCategory: UIContentSizeCategory
    switch UIApplication.shared.preferredContentSizeCategory {
    case .extraSmall, .small, .medium:
        preferredContentSizeCategory = .large
    case .accessibilityExtraLarge, .accessibilityExtraExtraLarge, .accessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge:
        preferredContentSizeCategory =  .accessibilityLarge
    default:
        preferredContentSizeCategory = UIApplication.shared.preferredContentSizeCategory
    }
    let traitCollection = UITraitCollection(preferredContentSizeCategory: preferredContentSizeCategory)
    let fontDescriptor = UIFontDescriptor.preferredFontDescriptor(withTextStyle: textStyle, compatibleWith: traitCollection)
    let fontMetrics = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: textStyle)
    let font: UIFont
    if let weight = weight {
        font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontDescriptor.pointSize, weight: weight)
    } else {
        font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontDescriptor.pointSize)
    }
    return fontMetrics.scaledFont(for: font, maximumPointSize: fontDescriptor.pointSize, compatibleWith: traitCollection)
}
```